# Codeception Cest Inheritance

Tags: testing, codeception

I'm not sure if Cest files can be extended. In the [documentation](http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Cest-Classes) says you can extend your Cest classes to share common behaviour. But every time I try to run my tests I get and class not found exception.

It's the documentation wrong or I'm doing something wrong?

Right now my base class look like this.

```
class ServiceCest {
  ...
}
```

And the child class looks like this.

```
class CreateServiceCest extends ServiceCest {...}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply `require_once 'ServiceCest.php';`  at the top of CreateServiceCest.php

More advanced ways are to configure autoloading in composer.json
https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4

Or to setup Codeception Autoloader in _bootstrap.php http://codeception.com/docs/reference/Autoload